# How can I group equivalent items together in a Python list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list like

```
x = [2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

I would like to put the repeated numbers together like

```
[[2,2],[1,1,1,1,1,1]]
```

Comment: What about `[2,2,1,1,1,2,2]`? Should it be `[[2,2],[1,1,1],[2,2]]` or `[[2,2,2,2],[1,1,1]]`?

Answer (score 27):

```
[list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(iterable)]
```

This is exactly what [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is for.

If you want nonconsecutive numbers grouped, like in the comment by @Michal,

```
[list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(iterable))]
```

Comment: Nice trick. What would this solution work for? I mean iterables of ints, floats, strings I guess it's ok. How about iterables of your own class objects ? Would these work if __eq__ or __hash__ is implemented ?

Comment: So long as they compare equal it will work; code equivalent to the implementation is at the link in my answer. So, just implement `__eq__` (and also `__hash__` because objects that are equal need to hash the same) and it will work.

Comment: You don't need `__hash__` just for this code to work, but it's a good idea to implement it so that your objects can be used effectively in dicts and sets.