# How to group similar items in a list?

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

I am looking to group similar items in a list based on the first three characters in the string.  For example:

```
test = ['abc_1_2', 'abc_2_2', 'hij_1_1', 'xyz_1_2', 'xyz_2_2']
```

How can I group the above list items into groups based on the first grouping of letters (e.g. `'abc'`)? The following is the intended output:

```
output = {1: ('abc_1_2', 'abc_2_2'), 2: ('hij_1_1',), 3: ('xyz_1_2', 'xyz_2_2')}
```

or

```
output = [['abc_1_2', 'abc_2_2'], ['hij_1_1'], ['xyz_1_2', 'xyz_2_2']]
```

---

I have tried using `itertools.groupby` to accomplish this without success:

```
>>> import os, itertools
>>> test = ['abc_1_2', 'abc_2_2', 'hij_1_1', 'xyz_1_2', 'xyz_2_2']
>>> [list(g) for k.split("_")[0], g in itertools.groupby(test)]
[['abc_1_2'], ['abc_2_2'], ['hij_1_1'], ['xyz_1_2'], ['xyz_2_2']]
```

---

I have looked at the following posts without success:

[How to merge similar items in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370294/how-to-merge-similar-items-in-a-list).  The example groups similar items (e.g. `'house'` and `'Hose'`) using an approach that is overly complicated for my example.

[How can I group equivalent items together in a Python list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025581/how-can-i-group-equivalent-items-together-in-a-python-list).  This is where I found the idea for the list comprehension.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `.split("_")[0]` part should be inside a single-argument function that you pass as the second argument to `itertools.groupby`.

```
>>> import os, itertools
>>> test = ['abc_1_2', 'abc_2_2', 'hij_1_1', 'xyz_1_2', 'xyz_2_2']
>>> [list(g) for _, g in itertools.groupby(test, lambda x: x.split('_')[0])]
[['abc_1_2', 'abc_2_2'], ['hij_1_1'], ['xyz_1_2', 'xyz_2_2']]
>>>
```

Having it in the `for ...` part does nothing since the result is immediately discarded.

---

Also, it would be slightly more efficient to use [`str.partition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) when you only want a single split:

```
[list(g) for _, g in itertools.groupby(test, lambda x: x.partition('_')[0])]
```

Demo:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit("'hij_1_1'.split('_')")
1.3149855638076913
>>> timeit("'hij_1_1'.partition('_')")
0.7576401470019234
>>>
```

This isn't a major concern as both methods are pretty fast on small strings, but I figured I'd mention it.

Comment: Thanks, this works great.  I recently found that it is a good practice to make sure the input list is sorted e.g. `test = sorted(['abc_1_2', 'abc_2_2', 'hij_1_1', 'xyz_1_2', 'xyz_2_2'])`.  Otherwise, if the input list is not sorted,  `itertools.groupby` will not work as expected.

Comment: Yes, sorting the list first is a good practice when using `itertools.groupby`.  This is because `groupby` only captures runs of similar values.  Meaning, it can miss some if the list is not sorted.  I didn't bother mentioning this in my post though because the main focus was on how to use `groupby` and also your list was already sorted.