# How to group related .tif files?

Tags: python, tiff, python-itertools

I am attempting to group related files associated with a .tif image.  You can see from the list that there are 7 related files per group.  I am looking for a way to group these files so that I can move them via `shutil.move()` into various folders.

The following script is what I have unsuccessfully attempted based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27659180/1446289).  The result is the same as the input `files` list.

How can I tweak this to perform the groupings I am after?

```
import os, itertools

files = ['F:\\juniper_project\\data\\raster\\deliverables\\OR\\reclass\\reclass_4511759_sw.tfw',
       'F:\\juniper_project\\data\\raster\\deliverables\\OR\\reclass\\reclass_4511759_sw.tif',
       'F:\\juniper_project\\data\\raster\\deliverables\\OR\\reclass\\reclass_4511759_sw.tif.aux.xml',
       'F:\\juniper_project\\data\\raster\\deliverables\\OR\\reclass\\reclass_4511759_sw.tif.ovr',
       'F:\\juniper_project\\data\\raster\\deliverables\\OR\\reclass\\reclass_4511759_sw.tif.vat.cpg',
       'F:\\juniper_project\\data\\raster\\deliverables\\OR\\reclass\\reclass_4511759_sw.tif.vat.dbf',
       'F:\\juniper_project\\data\\raster\\deliverables\\OR\\reclass\\reclass_4511759_sw.tif.xml',
       'F:\\juniper_project\\data\\raster\\deliverables\\OR\\reclass\\reclass_4511760_sw.tfw',
       'F:\\juniper_project\\data\\raster\\deliverables\\OR\\reclass\\reclass_4511760_sw.tif',
       'F:\\juniper_project\\data\\raster\\deliverables\\OR\\reclass\\reclass_4511760_sw.tif.aux.xml',
       'F:\\juniper_project\\data\\raster\\deliverables\\OR\\reclass\\reclass_4511760_sw.tif.ovr',
       'F:\\juniper_project\\data\\raster\\deliverables\\OR\\reclass\\reclass_4511760_sw.tif.vat.cpg',
       'F:\\juniper_project\\data\\raster\\deliverables\\OR\\reclass\\reclass_4511760_sw.tif.vat.dbf',
       'F:\\juniper_project\\data\\raster\\deliverables\\OR\\reclass\\reclass_4511760_sw.tif.xml']

test = sorted(files)
grouped = [list(g) for _, g in itertools.groupby(test, lambda x: x.split('_')[1])]
```

---

**Intended output:**

```
[['F:\\juniper_project\\data\\raster\\deliverables\\OR\\reclass\\reclass_4511759_sw.tfw',
           'F:\\juniper_project\\data\\raster\\deliverables\\OR\\reclass\\reclass_4511759_sw.tif',
           'F:\\juniper_project\\data\\raster\\deliverables\\OR\\reclass\\reclass_4511759_sw.tif.aux.xml',
           'F:\\juniper_project\\data\\raster\\deliverables\\OR\\reclass\\reclass_4511759_sw.tif.ovr',
           'F:\\juniper_project\\data\\raster\\deliverables\\OR\\reclass\\reclass_4511759_sw.tif.vat.cpg',
           'F:\\juniper_project\\data\\raster\\deliverables\\OR\\reclass\\reclass_4511759_sw.tif.vat.dbf',
           'F:\\juniper_project\\data\\raster\\deliverables\\OR\\reclass\\reclass_4511759_sw.tif.xml'],
           ['F:\\juniper_project\\data\\raster\\deliverables\\OR\\reclass\\reclass_4511760_sw.tfw',
           'F:\\juniper_project\\data\\raster\\deliverables\\OR\\reclass\\reclass_4511760_sw.tif',
           'F:\\juniper_project\\data\\raster\\deliverables\\OR\\reclass\\reclass_4511760_sw.tif.aux.xml',
           'F:\\juniper_project\\data\\raster\\deliverables\\OR\\reclass\\reclass_4511760_sw.tif.ovr',
           'F:\\juniper_project\\data\\raster\\deliverables\\OR\\reclass\\reclass_4511760_sw.tif.vat.cpg',
           'F:\\juniper_project\\data\\raster\\deliverables\\OR\\reclass\\reclass_4511760_sw.tif.vat.dbf',
           'F:\\juniper_project\\data\\raster\\deliverables\\OR\\reclass\\reclass_4511760_sw.tif.xml']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close! The index on the split list is one off, it should be 2.

Try

```
grouped = [list(g) for _, g in itertools.groupby(test, lambda x: x.split('_')[2])]
```

Comment: Thanks, I notice that it works for this example, but if there is a file named `4511760_se`, it would be lumped into `files[1]` because the direction `se` is not taken into account.  I suppose one (less flexible) work-around would be to slice the path: `[list(g) for _, g in itertools.groupby(test, lambda x: x[63:73])]`

Comment: If you're sure your key will always be numeric you can filter for that in your list instead of trying to select the key by index